# jQuery scope - Why isn't my array being populated?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a JSON file that contains information for a set of tweets, and I'm trying to populate an array with the raw text of each tweet. There are 95 tweets in the set, so the array should have 95 items in it (each item will be a string containing the raw text of the tweet).

Here is my code:

```
// Declaring array to hold tweets
allTweets = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Going through JSON file to get raw text from tweets
  $.getJSON("TwitterTweets17.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $.each(val, function(key2, val2) {
          // Only getting raw text from tweets, no other info
          if (key2 === "text") {
            allTweets.push(val2);
          }
      });
    });
  });

  console.log("allTweets length: " + allTweets.length);

  for (i = 0; i < allTweets.length; i++) {
      console.log(allTweets[i]);
  }
})
```

When I run this code, I get this output in the console:

```
allTweets length: 0
```

This doesn't make much sense to me. I declared the **allTweets** array as globally as I could, but it still doesn't seem like the array is being populated. Moving the console.log and for loop outside of the $(document).ready function does not change the output. Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: To be more thorough with this question, here is alternate code that *does* give the output I want:

```
// Declaring array to hold tweets
allTweets = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Going through JSON file to get raw text from tweets
  $.getJSON("TwitterTweets17.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $.each(val, function(key2, val2) {
        // Only getting raw text from tweets, no other info
        if (key2 === "text") {
          allTweets.push(val2);
        }
      });
    });

    console.log("allTweets length: " + allTweets.length);

    for (i = 0; i < allTweets.length; i++) {
      console.log(allTweets[i]);
    }
  });
})
```

And this is the approximate console output:

```
allTweets length: 95
RT @1942bs: "why don't y'all just give Trump a chance"
RT @JuddLegum: Trump said the exact same thing and was elected president.
...
```

And so on. Basically it shows all the tweets. So I guess my question is, why does it work in this case but not the previous?

Comment: Show your json data too..

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my question was clear enough. I don't think it's a problem with the JSON, because in my (edited) answer, I show a case where it does get the correct output. My question is: why does the second case work but not the first? Thanks.

Comment: In your first example, you are displaying the tweets in the _success_ handler, after the JSON has been loaded and the array populated.  In the second, you're calling GetJSON and the success handler populates the array, but then you immediately continue to show the output of allTweets before the tweets have actually be loaded and pushed into the array.

Comment: Okay I'll have to reread that a few times to understand it fully haha, thanks for the explanation though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the getJSON is ajax call and its synchronous XMLHttpRequest you can turn it off async: false put this above your code.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});
```

BTW its will async globally all your ajax calls. you can use the `$.ajax` instead and just async: false this call only like this.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'TwitterTweets17.json',
    dataType:'json',
    async:false,
    success:function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
          $.each(val, function(key2, val2) {
              // Only getting raw text from tweets, no other info
              if (key2 === "text") {
                allTweets.push(val2);
              }
          });
        });
    }
});
```